# How can I disable input field spaces with MooTools?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, mootools, field

I can't find this anywhere, we need to disable the space bar (spaces) in a input field of our form using MooTools 1.2

I have a solution for jQuery which doesn't work, however we have our site based completely on our framework of choice.

Thank you for your help!!

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
<input id='username' name='signup_username' type='text' class='home_signin_field' maxlength='50' size='22' onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Your Name':this.value;" value="Your Name">
</form>
```

Comment: why not checking the content of the "input field" and deleting spaces?

Comment: Because I'm not everyone else signing up who don't understand how spaces effect URL rewriting rules

Comment: you can also enforce input masks via recipes as well as custom regex. eg http://mootools.net/forge/p/meiomask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use mootools, but it looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('username').addEvent('keydown', function(event){
        if (event.key == 'space') { event.stop(); return false; } 
});
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVC7d/12/